# Cant display data from JSON in canvasjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, canvasjs

hi and sorry for silly question i miss some part of code and cant figure it out, I did from this lesson https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/json-data-api-ajax-chart/ and when I'm editing code to put my json api and values nothing happens....(values from json are telemetry only 'timestamp' and 'cpu' value)
my code is :

```
  window.onload = function() {

  var dataPoints = [];
  var cpuPoints = [];

  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    theme: "light2",
    title: {
        text: "consume timeline"
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "cpu use",
        titleFontSize: 24,

    },
    data: [{
        type: "column",
        yValueFormatString: "#,### Units",
        dataPoints: dataPoints
    }]
  });

  function addData(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        dataPoints.push({
            x: new Date(data[i].timestamp),
            y: data[i].cpu
        });
    }
    chart.render();

  }

  $.getJSON("http://192.168.13.60:12345/api/metric/cpu", addData);

  }
```

please can somebody help me figure it out. I think i miss some variable to declare

Comment: Check the browser's console. is there any error?

Comment: from web console i recive and see GET methods with correct response in it.
only wierd thing which appears is Error in parsing value for ‘line-height’.  Declaration dropped.